# How to use provider for dependency injection using guice in playframework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, guice, playframework-2.4

I am using playframework 2.4 here is my code

```
trait UserRepositoryTrait {
  val userRepo:UserRepository
  val sessionRepo:SessionRepository 
}

class UserRepositoryImpl extends UserRepositoryTrait {
  @Inject @Named("userRepo")val userRepo:UserRepository= null 
  @Inject @Named("sessionRepo") val sessionRepo:SessionRepository = null
  }
```

and here is module class

```
class UserDependencyModule extends AbstractModule { 

    @Override
      protected def configure() {
        bind(classOf[UserRepository]).annotatedWith(Names.named("userRepo")).toInstance(new UserRepo)
        bind(classOf[SessionRepository]).annotatedWith(Names.named("sessionRepo")).toInstance(new SessionRepo)
                bind(classOf[UserRepositoryTrait]).to(classOf[UserRepositoryImpl])
      }

}
```

in application.conf

```
play.modules.enabled += "models.guice.UserDependencyModule"
```

everything works fine if I inject this trait in a controller but i want to inject this trait into a class here is the code

```
class StatusChange @Inject() (userRepository:UserRepositoryTrait) {
}
```

and i need to call`StatusChange.scala` in `Service.scala` class 
how can i instantiate `StatusChange.scala` object

```
class ArtworkService() {

val status= new StatusChange(//what should i add here?)

}
```

i did read on providers but I am unable to understand how can I use it for my scenario ?please guide me

**update**
if i do it like this will be correct ?

```
class ArtworkService @inject (userRepository: UserRepositoryTrait) {

    val status= new StatusChange(userRepository)

    }
```

and in the controller

```
class MyController @inject (userRepository: UserRepositoryTrait)
{
 val artworkService = new ArtworkService(userRepository)
}
```

Comment: Your ArtworkService will also need to inject a UserRepositoryTrait.

Comment: then how can i pass UserRepostiryTrait argument to ArtworkService class the problem still persists (the class will change only) i need to know how to pass these arguments which requires the @injected instances

Comment: Fundamentally the question is: what is the root of the stack trace of the thread that will create your `ArtworkService`? In other words what makes that code run? If this is a chain of calls that originates from some Controller, than you can have a chain of relevant @Inject along the way (in the reverse direction i.e. every time injecting the component that will be called). If the code is run by some other means, how exactly is it run?

Comment: its run by a controller please see the question again i have edited it

Comment: @swaheed, It is still not clear what is the problem for you with a straightforward approach of `class MyController @Inject() (artworkService : ArtworkService)`

Comment: I can't understand what is the problem? what is the error you have?
I think you can just do:
`
  class ArtworkService @Inject() (statusChange: StatusChange) {}

  class MyController @Inject() (artworkService: ArtworkService) {}
`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use provider here. [Provider](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Managing-circular-dependencies) is useful to resolve cyclic dependency references.

In your case, you can simply do:

```
class ArtworkService @Inject (status: StatusChange) {}
```

And then direct inject `ArtworkService` in your controller:

```
class MyController @Inject (artworkService: ArtworkService) {}
```

[Provider](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Managing-circular-dependencies) would have come into the picture, if you had a cycle reference. For example:

```
class ArtworkService @Inject (status: StatusChange) {}

class StatusChange @Inject (artworkService: ArtworkService) {}
```

Here, we have cycle `ArtworkService` -> `StatusChange` && `StatusChange` -> `ArtworkService` So, provider comes in rescue in these situations. You can resolve this by:

```
class ArtworkService @Inject (status: StatusChange) {}

class StatusChange @Inject (artworkServiceProvider: Provider[ArtworkService]) {}
```